# How to delete item from mongodb on click of font awesome icon?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am working on a inventory application and trying to delete item from mongodb when `delete` font awesome icon is clicked.

I looked at the MDN docs local library project [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms) but they are using a dedicated route with hidden form input to delete item. I can't seem to figure out how to code pug file so that when icon is clicked delete route is triggered in categories controller.
[image]

**Category_detail.pug**

```
extends layout 
block head 
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/category_detail.css")
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/abb39a57a2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
block content 
    h1 #{category.name} 
    table
        thead 
            tr 
                th Item name 
                th Price 
                th Update 
                th Delete
        tbody 
            each item in items
                tr 
                    td #{item.itemName}
                    td #{item.price}
                    td
                        //- Update iten details 
                        a(href="#") 
                            i(class="fas fa-edit")
                    td 
                        //- Delete item 
                        form(method="POST" action='')
                            div.form-group
                                input(type="hidden", name='itemid',required="true", value=item._id )
                            a()
                                i(class="fas fa-trash" type='submit')
                            
                        //- a(href="#")
                            //- i(class="fas fa-trash")
```

Here is my [github](https://github.com/MubashirWaheed/Inventory-Application) if you want to see any other file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here is the code for update icon

**Pug file**

```
td
  //- Update iten details 
      a( href=`/categories/${category._id}/update/${item._id}` class="updatebtn" data-updateid=`${item._id}`) 
        i(class="fas fa-edit")
```

I simply added `href` to the anchor tag which contains the `id` of item that was clicked.After that in backend I used `req.param.id` to get the id of particular item clicked.

**itemController**

```
exports.itemUpdate_get = (req, res)=>{
    Items.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('category')
    .exec(function(err, data){
        res.render('item_form', {itemData: data});
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is a pug, but i knew HTML..
Also I am noob..
First thing, we can't click on   tag..so, Instead we can add a click function on   anchor tag and write our logic..(in your case, it's a delete logic)..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well this is not helping